# An example that the sum of two Borel sets which is not a Borel set in n-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

By sum of two sets I mean $A+B := \{x+y:x \in A \quad y \in B\}$, and there is a tip in a book of real analysis by Zhou Minqiang which says:

“If $A,B$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A+B$ may not be a Borel set.”

I want to know some specific examples.(Maybe $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ ?)

Any comments will be helpful.

Comment: I heard that we can construct a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ project to a non-Borel set. Is that true?

Comment: A closed set in $R^2$ is a countable union of compacts. So its projection is a countable union of compact sets. Therefore it is a Borel set.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Maybe just a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ @juan

Comment: Yes, there are Borel sets with projection non Borel.  Lebesgue, in one of his paper pretended to proof that the projection of a Borel set is a Borel set. Lusin detected the error. This started the Theory of analytic sets.  But the examples, I think, are always difficult.

Comment: @juan It was not Lusin who detected the error, but Souslin, a student of Lusin. This is why projections of Borel sets are called Souslin sets. Then Lusin and Sierpinski developed the major part of the theory of Souslin sets.

Comment: Is there a simple example?  Well, your set $A+B$ would be analytic but not Borel. Is there a "simple" example of that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a result of Erdos and Stone: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-02/S0002-9939-1970-0260958-1/S0002-9939-1970-0260958-1.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any easy example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's easy, but [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121270/must-the-minkowski-sum-of-a-borel-set-and-a-closed-ball-be-borel?_gl=1*od67x*_ga*ODkzMjgwNzYxLjE2ODU2ODIzNjg.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5MzI4NDE5Ny4xMjIuMS4xNjkzMjg1MDA0LjAuMC4w) provides another example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and can be generalized into the case $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\ge3$.

### Short Answer

The core idea is to exploit a non-Borel analytic set (a.k.a. Souslin set) $A'_1\subset[-1,1]$ which is also the image of the first projection of the Borel set $A'\subset[-1,1]^2$. This non-Borel set $A'_1$ is then mapped onto the cylinder

$$
\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x_2^2+x_3^2=1\right\}.
$$

Denoting it $A\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, then we get $(A+B(0,1))\cap(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}^2)=A'_1$, a scenario that is impossible if $A+B(0,1)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

### Long Explanation

For every uncountable Polish space, there exists a non-Borel Souslin set, as is explained in [Kechris 1995](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4190-4) p.85 Theorem 14.2.

Taking $X=[-1,1]$, we can construct a non-Borel Souslin set $A_1'\in\Sigma^1_1(X)\setminus\mathcal{B}(X)$, and using this $A_1'$ we are going to construct a counterexample for $n\ge3$.

Here, we are in need of the following characterization of Souslin sets:

> Theorem ([Bogachev 2007](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-34514-5) p.24 Theorem 6.7.2, Kechris 1995 p.86 14.3.)
> Let $X$ be a Souslin space, a Souslin set which is also Hausdorff, and let $A\subset X$ its subset. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is a Souslin set;
> 2. $A$ can be represented as $A=\mathrm{pr}_1(F)$, where $F\overset{\text{closed}}{\subset} X\times\mathbb{N}^\infty$;
> 3. $A$ can be represented as $A=\mathrm{pr}_1(B)$, where $B\subset X\times\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable.

Here we take $X:=[-1,1]$ and $A:=A_1'$, we can find a Borel measurable subset $A'\subset[-1,1]^2$ such that $A_1'=\mathrm{pr}_1(A')$.

The next step is crucial, where we map the Borel subset $A'$ to a cylinder
$$
C:=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x_2^2+x_3^2=1\},
$$
using a homeomorphism $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfies
$$
\psi([-1,1]\times\{0\})\subset\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}.
$$
Such a homeomorphism $\psi$ takes the segment $[-1,1]$ on the $x_1$-axis into the unit circumference $S^1$ in the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane.

Using $\psi$ as a building block, we constract a homeomorphism $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3):=(x_1,\psi(x_2,x_3)).
$$
Such a homeomorphism $\Psi$ pastes the set $A'$ onto the surface of the cylinder $C$.

Thus, $A:=\Psi(A')\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ now satisfies the following properties:
$$
\biggl(A+B(0,1)\biggr)\cap\biggl(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}^2\biggr)=A_1',
$$
where $A_1'\notin\mathcal{B}(X)$ is non-Borel and $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a closed unit ball centered at the origin. This scenario is impossible if $A+B(0,1)$ is Borel measurable, since $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}^2$ is Borel measurable.

This idea is stimulated from [Lurio et. al. 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0430), Example 2.4.

Comment: True Appreciation for such a specific counterexample.

Comment: and if you can write it down as a self-contained answer I'll merge such kind of questions in SE.(If I have time)

Comment: @YOTAL Happy if that helped! I've just updated it!